# Sentence meaning

Tags: sentence-meaning

> His hurt expression and absent apology stirred little guilt in her
>   hardened bosom.

1. "**Hurt expression**" and "**Absent apology**" are contradicting each other.  "**Hurt expression**" means an expression that shows hurt, unhappiness. 
   **Absent** is defined in oxford dictionaries  "(Of an expression or manner) showing that someone is not paying attention to what is being said or done", meaning that his apology was distracted, half-hearted, or perfunctory.  Am I right?
2. Does "**hardened bosom**" mean her feelings and emotions lack sympathy or pity?

Comment: Please rewrite your title so people can know what your real question is without looking at the body. This will help future visitors to our site.

Comment: I have to point out that the example sentence is pretty bad writing: an attempt at 'literariness' by someone who doesn't use English with great precision. [Source](https://www.fictionpress.com/s/1499620/1/Thinking-Too-Much-and-Loving-Not-Enough).

Comment: @StoneyB I didn't know about that source. I usually learn the language through studying a lot of example sentences. This was taken from Oxford Dictionaries.  But I believe you can only view more example sentences if you have the premium subscription.(http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/absent).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I agree with all of your interpretations.

*Absent apology* could also mean an apology that is *missing*.  Perhaps he did not apologize, and that is why she does not feel guilty.  This seems less likely than your interpretation, but without **more context**, it is hard to know for sure.

The sentence does seem to be contradictory, because his *hurt expression* suggests that he is sincere, and *absent apology* suggests that he is not.  But that is what the sentence says, and of course people sometimes do contradictory things.  Again, **more context** might explain what is really going on here.

Comment: Thank you for answering. This sentence was taken from Oxford Dictionaries as it is. It is supposed to be an English learning sentence. With respect to your interpretation, I thought that  the sentence means  she did feel guilty, correct?

Comment: Not really.  Note the word *little*.  Taken literally it means she felt a small amount of guilt, but using *little* in this way has a negative sense - it emphasizes that she felt much less guilt than you might expect, perhaps practically none.  *Little* here could be replaced by *no* without really changing the meaning.

Comment: That clarifies a lot. How about my question 2? what does "hardened bosom" mean, is my interpretation right?

Comment: @Ghaith: I said I agreed with *all* your interpretations, including that one :-)